# Are there any good reasons to NOT symlink 'System Folders' like Photos or Music?

Tags: folders, symlink, icloud

I am currently adopting [oDrive](https://www.odrive.com/) for all my cloud storage needs. The only restriction that oDrive has it that it creates a folder called 'ODRIVE' on your computer. Everything that you want to sync has to go in that folder. I have now symlinked my Creative Cloud folder (for adobe CC) but I would REALLY like to symlink my Movies, Music, Documents, etc. That way oDrive manages my backup process, I continue using my usual workflow of saving photos to Photos and music to Music.

But I'm uncertain of how the Apple OS treats those folders. As I believe they are "System Folders" and have requirements on them.

So is there any good reason to NOT symlink 'System Folders?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is fine! Go ahead!**

Symlinks or hard links are followed by the system, so you're free to create them within any of those folders, or indeed the folder itself.